# Checking whether a given input is present in a File

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I am doing a mini project on Inventory Management. I have an array list that has the contents. I update the arraylist from an admin login and update the list and i write them into a file.
But when a User logs in and requests the item that was updated, I am not able to recieve it. Is there anyway or any specific condition that will help me check whether the input given by the user is available in the file. I just want to compare the user input and check whether  it is present in the file

Comment: `...I am not able to recieve it` Does this mean that the file was written incorrectly? I suggest you verify the output in the file.

Comment: need some specific scenario

Answer (score 1):

You can do by reading a file by using BufferedReader and FileReader line by line and check input contains in a line.

```
public boolean checkInput(String input)
{
        FileReader in = new FileReader("C:/test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
              if(line.contains(input))
                return true;
        }
        in.close();
        return false;
}
```

Comment: might want to use the return type of boolean in that case.

Comment: i changed return type to boolean. it depends on how he wants to use..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

1. Take the input and keep it in a variable-say userInput
2. Pass it to a function, say checkInFile(userInput,FileName)
3. In the function, write the method Karunakar has posted.
4. Return true if it is present, and false if it is not.